# How to get deployments heatlh with python script using wlst

Tags: python, wlst

I´m trying to access to deployments health status in my web logic server via python script. I got status that is ACTIVE or INACTIVE but I don´t know how to get health status to know if deployments are OK or in WARNING helath status.

This is for a suse linux 10 server with a web logic 10.3.

```
cd ('AppDeployments')
myapps=cmo.getAppDeployments()
for appName in myapps:
        domainConfig()
        cd ('/AppDeployments/'+appName.getName()+'/Targets')
        mytargets = ls(returnMap='true')
        domainRuntime()
        cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
        cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
        for targetinst in mytargets:
            curstate4=cmo.getIntendedState(appName.getName(),targetinst)
            lines=[curstate4, '|', targetinst, '|', appName.getName(), '\n']
```

Then I write lines to a file.

I want to get HEALTH status from deployments instead of getting STATUS.

Comment: What are you expecting from "application health status" ? WebLogic provides only a status for each deployed application. If your application is Active, it is correctly deployed and ready for the service. 
A weblogic server instance has a health state but not the applications.

Comment: I was expecting a warning health state for example... Because a deployment can be in this state... @EmmanuelCollin